# I got Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ when trying to fetch json using Retrofit in Android (java)

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit, retrofit2

API Link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iranjith4/radius-intern-mobile/master/users.json

```
my API interface :

public interface Api {

String BASE_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iranjith4/radius-intern-mobile/master/";

    @GET("users.json")
    Call<List<UserModel>> getUsers();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON returns an object, not an array. The first character is `{`, not `[`.

You need to create a Java class that has a `results` field that is your `List<UserModel>`, and use that Java class in your return value from your Retrofit API. This would match the JSON, which has a `results` list that I assume is what you are looking to get from this JSON.

For example, you might have:

```
public class UserResponse {
  List<UserModel> results;
}
```

and:

```
@GET("users.json")
Call<UserResponse> getUserResponse();
```

Comment: @RaySk: Perhaps `UserModel` does not match the JSON. See if there are messages in LogCat suggesting what the problem is.

Comment: i wrote my Model call using jsonutils.com